# Why was Luke chosen as the last hope instead of Leia?

Tags: star-wars

Yoda and Kenobi chose Luke to make Jedi knight. Why? We've seen many female Jedi in the canon. Why couldn't Leia became a Jedi knight?

Comment: I don't think it's ever stated anywhere that she couldn't, she just never became one.

Comment: She was a Princess, likely with public showings where people [who able] could sense her medi-chlorians.  The answers need to dig deeper.  Maybe she was too public.

Comment: It's the same reason as why most movies have male protagonists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Luke wasn't "chosen" - he just happened to be the first to get around to, you know, **train** to become one.

   As is shown in ROTS, they were BOTH intended to be trained as Jedi, and the timing of the training was pretty much left by Yoda to the Force.

   > ... Hidden, safe, the children must be kept. Foundation of the new Jedi Order, **they** will be."
   >
   > "We should split them up," Obi-Wan said. "Even if the Sith find one, the other may survive. I can take the boy, Master Yoda, and **you take the girl**. We can hide them away, keep them safe— train them as Anakin should have been trained—"
   > ... When right is the time for skills to be taught, to us the living Force will bring **them**. Until then, wait we will, and watch, and learn.

   Leia didn't get to be trained in Ep 4-6 since, by the time she met any of the Jedi to train her, they were... well, dead.
2. In addition, from EU canon, it's clear that Luke is significantly stronger in the Force than Leia is. Quite possiby, Yoda and Kenobi knew that from birth, though I'm not aware of any canon confirmation of it aside from the fact that at the time of their birth, Jedi had technology to measure Midichlorian counts. That wasn't really a factor, but should be stated given the context of the question.
3. Also, in EU canon (we'll see what Disney canon will be) Leia DID end up with some Jedi training at Luke's urging, but didn't go through with it since she was a complete slacker and didn't devote enough time and effort to her Jedi training.

Comment: Funny how Yoda leaves it up to the Force but, when the time *does* come, he complains about Luke being too old. Have it both ways, you cannot. Know this, Yoda should.

Comment: I had always interpreted it as Yoda sort of testing Luke's resolution and maturity. He complains that Luke was not the type to finish what he starts and essentially goads him into committing himself. And to be fair, Yoda was partially vindicated when Luke failed the cave trial.

Comment: Also, Yoda had a good statistical reason - 100% of Skywalkers who started training late in life became Sith.

Comment: 100% of Skywalkers? Who else is in your list than Anakin?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - 1 of 1 is 100%.

Comment: :D Fine. But, this can't make Skywalker plural.

Answer (score 7):

Luke's training, even if *very* basic, began when Ben handed Luke his father's lightsaber. **He was chosen out of necessity, to answer Leia's call for help.**

From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/quotes?qt=qt0440667):

> *Princess Leia*: General Kenobi. Years ago you served my father in the
> Clone Wars. Now he begs you to help him in his struggle against the
> Empire. I regret that I am unable to convey my father's request to you
> in person, but my ship has fallen under attack, and I'm afraid my
> mission to bring you to Alderaan has failed. I have placed information
> vital to the survival of the Rebellion into the memory systems of this
> R2 unit. My father will know how to retrieve it. You must see this
> droid safely delivered to him on Alderaan. This is our most desperate
> hour. Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope.   [pause]
>
> *Obi-Wan*: [to Luke] **You must learn the ways of the Force, if you're to
> come with me to Alderaan.**
>
> *Luke*: Alderaan? I'm not going to Alderaan,
> I've gotta get *home*, it's late, I'm in for it as it is!
>
> *Obi-Wan*: I
> need your help, Luke. She needs your help. I'm getting too old for
> this sort of thing.

<sup>bold face added to indicate the relevant part of the script</sup>

Answer (score 0):

And Obi Wan apparently didn't know that Leia was Luke's sister anyway.  If I understood it correctly, I don't think he found out who leia was until Luke left Dagobah in Episode V as it was then he said 'that boy is our last hope' to which Yoda replies with, "No, there is another.".

Of course the prequels throw that into question since he was there at their birth and handed Leia to her father so who knows what the real answer is.

As has been mentioned, Leia eventually becomes a Jedi in her own right, but not until she leaves governmental service in the New Republic.  The Thrawn Trilogy opens with her indicating she had received some training from Luke, but it was only rudimentary in many ways.

Comment: Apart from Lucas kind of making the story up as he went, Obi-Wan could have meant that he didn't consider Leia a "hope" as she was not showing as much promise and prowess with the force as her brother. In fact, Luke wasn't even able to beat the Emperor on his own. He needed his father's assistance. It's doubtful that Leia could have served the same purposes. Especially since they had a limited time frame to beat the Emperor. Sooner or later he would have been in absolute power and Leia, even if she was talented enough, would have taken to long to become powerful enough to make a difference.