# Why does Obi-Wan think so lowly of Leia?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Fess Ilee (Ferus Olin) thought that there was the Dark Side in Luke, but only light in Leia. He was a Jedi, so he was probably correct. Why did Obi-Wan only see anything in Luke? Leia, her whole life, was a natural leader. Luke only started to come around in Episode V and VI. What did Luke have that Leia didn't, in Obi-Wan's eyes?

Comment: Where are you getting this idea he thought lowly of her from?  Luke and Leia we’re separated for their safety and Obi-Wan could only watch one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did Obi-Wan Kenobi prefer Luke over Leia?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92566/did-obi-wan-kenobi-prefer-luke-over-leia) It doesn't answer your question directly but does address your premise that Obi-Wan thought less of Leia than of Luke.

Comment: There is also the real world answer at that time, Lucas had a hard time selling his story as is, it would be near impossible to sell an action movie where the hero is female.

Comment: "He was a Jedi, so he was probably correct." Considering the Jedi failed to notice *the Dark Lord of the Sith* was handing out orders from the Chancellor's office for almost a decade, I don't think their perceptions of light and dark potential can really be trusted.